# How to change date's format from milliseconds

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am receiving last modification date of a file, using below code:

```
xmlUrl = new URL("http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html");
URLConnection urlconn = xmlUrl.openConnection();
urlDate =  new Date(urlconn.getLastModified());
```

In result I am getting date in below format:

```
Tue Dec 18 05:11:33 Asia/Karachi 2007
```

I want to change it to simple dd MMM yyyy format

I used:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
try {
        tempDate = format.parse(urlDate.toString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it didn't help me to solve the issue and I am still getting the date in that above mentioned long format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tempDate = format.parse(urlDate.toString());
```

That's backwards and should lead to an exception. A `DateFormat` is for converting between `String` and `Date` both ways, and the format string must always match the pattern of the `String` side.

What you want is this:

```
tempDate = format.format(urlDate);
```

Comment: tempDate = format.format(urlDate)

is not working, as format(Date) method, returns a string and tempDate is a Date type variable.

what I did created

DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
tempDate = format.format(urlDate);

even I tried to cast it but no use :(

Comment: @kaibuki: a Date does not *have* a format, it's always a timestamp with millisecond precision. If you want to display it in a specific format, that means turning it into a String.